# I have customized my Ubuntu Live USB, should I expect the same customization after installing to a hard drive?

Tags: customization, live-usb

I think the question is rather self-explanatory, however: say I have customized my Live USB (enabled with disk persistence) with installed software, desktop background, config files, etc.

1. Are these customization going to last between sessions?
2. Should I expect to have the same customizations on a target machine after installing Ubuntu from the USB drive?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, I'm afraid not.  The live USB is self-contained within the persistence file - when you install Ubuntu, there's no option to migrate those settings into your clean install.

For example, my Live CD with persistence has an install of clamAV, and panel applets to show CPU, frequency and temperature.  It's also connected to my WIFI.  However, when I use that key to install, I get the stock install - no clamAV, none of my customised panel applets, and I have to re-connect to my WIFI.

Sorry.

With regards to your first question - your customisations on the Live USB will remain in place when you use that Live USB, regardless of which PC you run it on.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Live USB will only be customized on itself. When you install to a pc you're writing to the computer from the actual ISO image and it's files...there will be no customization until you customize it again.